# Max and min value from each and every excel sheet in a workbook

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Want to find max and min value  and average from each and every sheet present in an excel file using powershell and create a new sheet as summary.

I tried using max min but could not get it

Comment: Can you show us the code which you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory (maybe you should try  [Chat-GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT) instead). You will need to write the) script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)